# Vuejs: Can't change ref inside function but can do from template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Am trying to learn Vue and have come across the below issue/problem.

```
<template>
    <div>{{ name }}</div>
    <button @click="name = 'changed name'">Change</button>
</template>
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    let name = ref('first');
</script>
```

The above works, when I click on the button, the text inside the div is changed to **changed name**. But the below does not work, is the variable `name` not available in the function? Have used `defineExpose({name})` also, still does not work.

```
<template>
    <div>{{ name }}</div>
    <button @click="changeName">Change</button>
</template>
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    let name = ref('first');
    const changeName = () => {
        name = 'changed name';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the template you can use the ref name. But inside the script you should use name.value.

```
    <script setup>
        import { ref } from 'vue';
        const name = ref('first');
        const changeName = () => {
            name.value = 'changed name';
        }
    </ script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part. Looks like with `reactive` I don't have to use `.value`

Comment: You should also define your refs as `const` instead of `let`, because the ref object will not change, only the value. This prevents the ref from being incidentally overwritten. You would then have gotten an ‘trying to change const’ error in your example.